# Float in Database to ? in .NET

Tags: .net, sql-server, types, floating-point, double

If you have a float in MSSQLServer, to what do you map this in .NET?

Can you convert it to Double or will you lose numbers?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

SQLServer `float` and C#/VB `double` have the same representation.  This is the correct mapping.  What you don't want to do is map SQL Server `float` to C#/VB `float` as that may involve a loss of precision.  SQL Server `real` maps onto C#/VB `float`.

T-SQL float and real type definitions can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx). C# double definition can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) as well, as can the float [definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx).

Comment: Wrong, though you can map any SQL-server float to a C# double, you can't map any C# double to a SQL-server float... But it usually works for "normally" large/tiny numbers

Comment: This isn't strictly true - even for REAL/FLOAT(24). SQL Server has no notion of NaN, or +/-Inf which are supported under standard IEEE754 (C#/VB.NET) rules.

Answer (score 16):

Check out:

- [SQL Server Data Types and Their .NET Framework Equivalents (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092(SQL.90).aspx) for full reference on data type mappings between SQL Server and .Net

In your case SQL Server native type **float** maps to SQL Server CLR **SqlDouble** and then **Double** in .Net

**Update (May 2016)**:

Updated version of the msdn document: [Mapping CRL Parameter Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.130%29.aspx)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Thanks for the link. There is an updated version by now. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.130%29.aspx

Comment: thanks @MatthisKohli - added the new link to the answer now

Answer (score 0):

C# has a float type, but it will convert to double just fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

From my recollection, most of the ORM tools will map it to a Decimal type, which will not lose precision like a double or float.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the SQL float.  For plain "float" which is equivalent to float(53), you need to use a C# double.  For float(24) or lower a C# float will be enough, or a double would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic code generated by Microsoft XSD convert SQL float (default float) to C# double.
So you can suggest that it isn't big mistake. 
Until you working with float that have default size.