# Float cast error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting

I defined Latitude Float(24) and Longitude Float(24) in my database(dinner table). And then when I tried to use them, the code shown as following in my model

```
  public class JsonDinner
{
    public JsonDinner(){}
    public JsonDinner(Dinner dinner)
    {
        DinnerID = dinner.DinnerID;
        EventDate = dinner.EventDate.ToString();
        Latitude =  dinner.Latitude;
        Longitude = dinner.Longitude;
        Title = dinner.Title;
        Description = dinner.Description;
        RSVPCount = dinner.RSVPs.Count;
        Url = "dinner/details/" + dinner.DinnerID.ToString();
    }

        public int    DinnerID    {get; set;}
        public string EventDate   {get; set;}
        public float  Latitude    {get; set;}
        public float  Longitude   {get; set;}
        public string Title       {get; set;}
        public string Description {get; set;}
        public int    RSVPCount   {get; set;}
        public string Url         {get; set;}
}
```

It said

> Cannot implicitly convert 'float' to 'float'. An explicitly conversion
>   exists(are you missing a cast)?

What I did wrong? I even didnt use any casting.

Comment: what line do you get the error?

Comment: can you also show the code in your `Dinner` class?

Comment: Can you try to define the float as 32?

Comment: Do you by chance have a class named `float` in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming out of the database, I believe `float` equates to C# `double`.  So make them:

```
Latitude =  (float)dinner.Latitude;
Longitude = (float)dinner.Longitude;
```

But understand that you're potentially reducing precision, so truncation/rounding becomes a real possibility.

Comment: Wouldn't it then be complaining about a double/float conversion?

Comment: No, because the type in the database is float.  Look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546150/float-in-database-to-in-net

Comment: Thanks all. @DonBoitnott's answer is correct. The error has disappeared. I defined float type for latitude and longitude, they equates to double type to C#, So I need to tell C# to cast the double number to float. But why they are not consistently working by the same way.hah