# DataRow.Field<T>(float Column) throws invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, sql-server

**IDE** Visual Studio 2015
**.NET"" 4.5
Platform WinForms

I have a database table with a column `[UsedSize] FLOAT`. When querying this table and storing the values in local variables I get an invalid cast exception; sample code:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    InfoLibrary ir = new InfoLibrary();
    ir.LibraryID = row.Field<int>("LibraryID");
    ir.Name = row.Field<string>("Name");
    ir.UsedSize = row.Field<float>("UsedSize");
    ir.TotalSize = row.Field<float>("TotalSize");
    ir.TotalFileCount = row.Field<int>("TotalFileCount");                   
    ilList.Add(ir);
}
```

When stepping the execution and performing a "Quick Watch" on the faulty line I discovered that, by changing the line to row.Field("TotalSize"), the cell value type is zero. Why would this happen when, in the table definition, this is clearly and `float`?

Comment: try using double instead

Comment: According to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546150/float-in-database-to-in-net) DB `FLOAT` is a C# `double`.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server float should map to a .Net Double see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)